# Evernote access_token can not be acquired

Tags: python-2.7, evernote

Access_token can not be acquired with OAuth of evernote API.
The following points are showing the error.

```
Client.get_access_token (request_token ['oauth_token'], request_token ['oauth_token_secret'], vals ['oauth_verifier'])
```

`Oauth_token`, `oauth_token_secret`, `oauth_verifier` can be acquired and outputted respectively.

The content of the error is like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build / bdist.linux-x86_64 / egg / evernote / api / client.py", line 67, in get_access_token
  File "build / bdist.linux-x86_64 / egg / evernote / api / client.py", line 58, in get_access_token_dict
KeyError: 'oauth_token'
```

I could not solve it even by examining, I asked a question here.
Do you know the cause?

I wrote the code referring to the following site.
https://gist.github.com/inkedmn/5041037

The following points are showing the error.

```
access_token = client.get_access_token (request_token ['oauth_token'], request_token ['oauth_token_secret'], vals ['oauth_verifier'])
```

Does the acquisition method be wrong?

The code is here.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding:utf-8

import evernote.edam.type.ttypes as Types
import evernote.edam.error.ttypes as Errors
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
import os

def parse_query_string(authorize_url):
    uargs = authorize_url.split('?')
    #vals = authorize_url.split('?')
    vals = {}
    if len(uargs) == 1:
        raise Exception('Invalid Authorization URL')
    for pair in uargs[1].split('&'):
        key, value = pair.split('=', 1)
        vals[key] = value
    return vals

CUNSUMER_KEY = 'MY_CUNSUMER_KEY'
CUNSUMER_SECRET = 'MY_CUNSUMER_SECRET'

client = EvernoteClient(
        consumer_key= CUNSUMER_KEY,
        consumer_secret= CUNSUMER_SECRET,
        #sandbox=True
        sandbox=False
    )

url = ""

if os.environ.has_key('HTTP_HOST') and os.environ.has_key('REQUEST_URI'):
    url = "http://" + os.environ['HTTP_HOST'] + os.environ['REQUEST_URI']

vals = parse_query_string(url)

request_token = client.get_request_token(url)

access_token = client.get_access_token(request_token['oauth_token'],request_token['oauth_token_secret'],vals['oauth_verifier'])

print 'Content-type: text/html\n'
print """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>vals</h1>
        <p>After the "?" Of the current URL</p>
        <p>%s</p>
        <h1>vals['oauth_verifier']</h1>
        <p>%s</p>
        <h1>request_token</h1>
        <p>%s</p>
        <h1>request_token['oauth_token']</h1>
        <p>%s</p>
        <h1>request_token['oauth_token_secret']</h1>
        <p>%s</p>
    </body>
</html>
"""%(vals, vals['oauth_verifier'], request_token, request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have got `request_token`? What does the entire code look like?

Comment: Is it working with `sandbox=True`?

Comment: Thank you, kentaro. The same error also appears in `sandbox = True`.